When I use provider inside bloc my simulator got stuck
I am making a page in flutter. I create bloc and then I call provider. In main page my code like that I have designed a 4-stage ad posting screen, I assign the values I get from each screen to changenotifier.
And I specified these stages with block states, I was taking the values from the provider at the last state and sending them to firebase, in fact, I made a few attempts, my code was working and then today I edit my folders, folder name file names and folder structure and I get problem when I click the page my simulator get stuck  nothing is working on the screen. And then I am doing hot restart debug console says
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<RegisterCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => RegisterCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<SignInCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => SignInCubit(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ListingProvider>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => ListingProvider(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<PostAdBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => PostAdBloc(context.read<ListingProvider>()),
          ),
        ],
        child: MainPage(),
      ) 

 ═╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building PostAdPage:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<PostAdBloc> above this BlocConsumer<PostAdBloc,
PostAdStates> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that BlocConsumer<PostAdBloc, PostAdStates> is under your
MultiProvider/Provider<PostAdBloc>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

I didn't get my code working very well, I just change the some folder structure etc
I try to hot restart redit. My logic is like I try the design post ad page I have designed a 4-stage name sharing screen, I assign the values I get from each screen to changenotifier. And I specified these stages with blockta states, I was taking the values from the provider at the last state and sending them to firebase, in fact, I made a few attempts, my code was working

It seems in providers in MultiProvider cannot depends on each other. You can try
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ListingProvider>(
      create: (_) => ListingProvider(),
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<RegisterCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => RegisterCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<SignInCubit>(
            create: (BuildContext context) => SignInCubit(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<PostAdBloc>(
            create: (BuildContext context) =>
                PostAdBloc(context.read<ListingProvider>()),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(),
      ),
    );
  }

